# How to execute Isabelle 2021 commandline commands from Windows 10?

Tags: isabelle

I have installed Isabelle 2021 version and now I would like to try command "isabelle export" as suggested in https://drops.dagstuhl.de/opus/volltexte/2020/13065/pdf/LIPIcs-TYPES-2019-1.pdf page 12, 2nd section of 15.1 chapter.

I can see 2 possibilities:

- There is main Isabelle2021.exe, but it start jEdit window and I carefully checked packaged jEdit options and I did't find the possibility that jEdit may server as the tool for entering isabelle command line commands.
- There are 3 scripts inside bin directory - `isabelle`, `isabelle_java`, `isabelle_scala_script`, I made copies as *.bat files for each of them and I have tried to run from Windows command line, but I got:

  C:\Homes\Isabelle2021\Isabelle2021\bin>isabelle_scala_script.bat export

  C:\Homes\Isabelle2021\Isabelle2021\bin>#!/usr/bin/env bash
  '#!' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
  operable program or batch file.

  C:\Homes\Isabelle2021\Isabelle2021\bin>#
  '#' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
  operable program or batch file.

So, these commands can be *nix related and may require running from cygwin, isn't it?

OK, now I am digesting the content of those 3 files, maybe I can tweak them for Windows. But it would be nice to hear what is the conventional, intended way of running Isabelle commands from Windows shell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is simple - there is Cygwin-Terminal.bat besides isabelle2021.exe and this *.bat opens the cygwin shell in which the isabelle command is available, including `isabelle export` with its options.