# How to use Isabelle's command line commands in macOS

Tags: isabelle, formal-verification

I have installed the Isabelle 2023 on my MacBook and I want to use command line commands to compile the proof. However, when I enter the command like `isabelle jedit -d . -l` the terminal just tell me command not found. There is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66728036/how-to-execute-isabelle-2021-commandline-commands-from-windows-10) deals with the same problem on Windows How to execute Isabelle 2021 commandline commands from Windows 10. But I cannot find the similar Cygwin-Terminal.bat on MacOS.

Comment: I don't have a mac, but you should write `/path/where/isabelle/is/installed/bin/isabelle` instead of just `isabelle`